# mySQL insert column with data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new table (table 2) with the data from an existing column of table 1:

**Table 1:**

id1 | item | type

=============

1 | item 1 | type B

2 | item 2 | type A

3 | item 3 | type A

4 | item 4 | type B

5 | item 5 | type C

**Table 2:**

id2 | type | count

===================

1 | type B | 2

2 | type A | 2

3 | type C | 1

id1 is not the same as id2

I've searched for answers and tried using: SET, UPDATE, INSERT JOIN with AS and FROM like some answers suggested but none of them works for me. How do I do it?

I used these keywords for my search: mysql create table with existing column, copy column from another table, insert column from another table, update column data from another table column...

Comment: You can tackle it in two steps - first write a SELECT statement on the first table that gets the results you want. Then use that SELECT to create the new table.

Comment: thanks @Jerry I can group all the type by SELECT type FROM table1 GROUP BY type; but then I don't know how to insert that selection to table 2. I tried: INSERT INTO table2 SELECT type FROM table1 GROUP BY type; but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's even easier than you think! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html - you can just use the select statement to define your table.

Comment: Of course if the data in table 1 changes, your table 2 will be out of date. If you have to keep the second table in sync with the first, consider using a VIEW instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just use a view table

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I've been able to create a new VIEW but the only way to add columns into it is by adding a single column each time using ALTER TABLE ADD.
Is there away I can create the new table using the VIEW column from the old table, plus several new columns?

Comment: Something like: CREATE TABLE new_table (
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
type CREATE VIEW type AS SELECT old_table.type FROM old_table GROUP BY type,
another column ... ,
another column ....,
...
);

Comment: Actually, I cannot even use ALTER TABLE to add column: error 1064.

Comment: is your several column data is coming also from another table ?